# error with email check and successful registartion

Tags: php, sql

```
echo "<h2>".$pagename."</h2>";
$User_FName = $_POST['U_fname'];
$User_SName = $_POST['U_sname'];
$User_Address = $_POST['U_address'];
$User_Postcode = $_POST['U_postcode'];
$User_telNo = $_POST['U_telNo'];
$User_Email = $_POST['U_email'];
$User_Password = $_POST['U_password'];
$User_confirmPassword = $_POST['U_confirmPassword'];

$emailCheck="SELECT userEmail FROM Users";
$exeEmailCheck=mysql_query($emailCheck) or die (mysql_error());
$emailArray=mysql_fetch_array($exeEmailCheck);


if (!empty($User_FName) AND !empty($User_SName) AND !empty($User_Address) AND !empty($User_Postcode) AND !empty($User_telNo) AND !empty($User_Email) AND !empty($User_Password) AND !empty($User_confirmPassword)) //empty is php function to check variables if empty
{
  if (!($User_Password==$User_confirmPassword)){
    echo "<p>Passwords don't match!</p>";
    echo "<p>Go back to <a href=register.php>register page</a></p>";
}
else{
    $reg = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';  

 if(preg_match($reg,$User_Email))
 {


    $addUserSQL=
        "insert into
    Users (userType,userFName, userSName, userAddress, userPostcode, userTelNo, userEmail, userPassword)
    values ('C','".$User_FName."', '".$User_SName."','".$User_Address."','".$User_Postcode."', '".$User_telNo."', '".$User_Email."', '".$User_Password."')";
    $exeaddUserSQL=mysql_query($addUserSQL);



   if(mysql_errno($conn) == 0 ){
        echo "<p>You've successfully registered";
        echo "<p>To continue, please <a href=login.php>login</a></p>";

    }
    else{
        echo "<p>You've not successfully registered</p>";
        if (mysql_errno($conn) == 1062){
    echo "<p>Email already taken</p>";
    echo "<p>Go back to <a href=register.php>register page</a></p>";
        }
    }   
}
else{
    "<p>Email not in the right format</p>";
}
}

} 

else{
    echo "<p>Please fill in all the fields</p>";


}
```

This part of the code does not run and I cannot figure out why and it allows me to register but does not put out the messages in the p tags.I tried to put the brackets in the right place but it still does not work

```
else{
    $reg = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';  

 if(preg_match($reg,$User_Email))
 {


    $addUserSQL=
        "insert into
    Users (userType,userFName, userSName, userAddress, userPostcode, userTelNo, userEmail, userPassword)
    values ('C','".$User_FName."', '".$User_SName."','".$User_Address."','".$User_Postcode."', '".$User_telNo."', '".$User_Email."', '".$User_Password."')";
    $exeaddUserSQL=mysql_query($addUserSQL);



   if(mysql_errno($conn) == 0 ){
        echo "<p>You've successfully registered";
        echo "<p>To continue, please <a href=login.php>login</a></p>";

    }
    else{
        echo "<p>You've not successfully registered</p>";
        if (mysql_errno($conn) == 1062){
    echo "<p>Email already taken</p>";
    echo "<p>Go back to <a href=register.php>register page</a></p>";
        }
    }   
}
else{
    "<p>Email not in the right format</p>";
}
}
```

Comment: don't use mysql_*, it is dead. Also your script can be SQL injected. Use PDO instead. Don't store plain passwords. and use this for email validation  `if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email_a) email address is considered valid.\n";
}`

Comment: That is a *terrible* email regexp

Comment: @Dimi I tried that its not working

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar  All that is coming up is registartion confirmation but what should come up is email is already taken and if the email is not in the right format it should say email not in right format the rest of the code works

Comment: @Abhisek Malakar All that is coming up is registartion confirmation but what should come up is email is already taken and if the email is not in the right format it should say email not in right format the rest of the code works

Comment: As per your presented code there is no checking for if the email is existing or not. So if the email address format is ok, then it always register.I have checked your regex, and it's fine so the provided email address is must be ok.

Comment: Abhisek Malakar does $email check  check if the email exist or not

Comment: @Abhisek Malakar what I want is the email comes in the right format so like hotmail.co.uk not hotuk or no at or hotcouk or hotcuk.Also some of the email they are already registers but it still goes through and the p tag for successful registered does not appear when everything is correct